# Change Mac Eclipse to Window Settings

Tags: c++, eclipse, windows, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

from my computer class last year, I have a bunch of c++ programs. I made these programs in Microsoft visual c++ 2010. That program I used it only available on Windows so I needed another program for I can still code. I now have a Mac and I want to still be able to code, so I downloaded Eclipse. My question is, how do I change the Eclipse setting to be the same as the windows? For example, when I copy my coding, it finds (using namespace std) and (#include ) as an error. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Which version of eclipse did you install? Unless you installed the versions of eclipse with C/C++ plugins, it's just a Java IDE.

But uh Eclipse kind of sucks anyways so I'd recommend trying [Clion](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/).

Comment: I downloaded the C++ version. And would Clio be able to do what I want it to do? With the using namespace std?

Comment: They should both be able to do it however clion is much more intuitive/straightforward to use IMO so I'd try that first.

Comment: Yeah, Clion is out of the question since I have a 30 day trial and would eventually have to pay. But any fix for Eclipse?

Comment: [It's free for students](https://www.jetbrains.com/student/) but beyond that please tell us how you setup your project etc. 

There are many things that could have gone wrong. Did you import from source? Is there a makefile? [If so, follow this guide.](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Fgetting_started%2Fcdt_w_existing_code.htm)

Comment: Would I have to put any information in? because of now, I am not in a C++ anymore, I do it on my free time after college.

Comment: No, the reason why it won't work is because I need the Microsoft Visual C++ toolchain for Eclipse, in which I don't even since I'm on a Mac. Any clue how to get one?

Comment: Unfortunately most of that is MS exclusive so you're going to need to change MS specific headers to their standard equivalents if you want it to work on other platforms.